# Unmet dependencies while installing Git on Debian

Tags: debian, apt, package-management, git, dependencies

I am attempting to install git on `Debian 8.6 Jessie` and have run into some dependency issues. What's odd is that I didn't have any issues the few times I recently installed `Git` in a VM while I was getting used to Linux.

`apt-get install git`

**Results in**:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
  git : Depends: liberror-perl but is not installable
        Recommends: rsync but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

**UPDATE**

my `sources.list`

[image]

Seems to be an issue with my system. I can no longer properly install anything. I'm getting dependency issues installing things like `Pulseaudio` which I've previously installed successfully a few days ago.

Comment: Try `sudo apt -f install` or `sudo aptitude -f`.

Comment: @phk 0 packages installed

Comment: Run `apt-get dist-upgrade && apt-get install git`

Comment: Please [edit here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/332862/edit) by adding the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: @GAD3R I can't seem to copy from the terminal or nano

Comment: @GAD3R Okay, sorry, I've added the scrot now.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You should edit your sources.list , by adding the following line:

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib
```

Then upgrade your package and install `git`:

```
apt-get update && apt-get upgrade && apt-get dist-upgrade
apt-get -f install
apt-get install git
```

**Edit**

the following package [`git`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/git/download) , [`liberror-perl`](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/all/liberror-perl/download) and `[rsync`][3](https://packages.debian.org/jessie/amd64/rsync/download) can be downloaded from the `main` repo , because you don't have the `main` repo on your `sources.list` you cannot install `git` and its dependencies .

Your `sources.list` should be (with `non-free` packages):

```
deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free

deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-updates main contrib non-free

deb http://ftp.ca.debian.org/debian/ jessie-backports main contrib non-free
```

On debian Stretch your `/etc/apt/sources.list` should be (at least):

```
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian stretch main
deb http://security.debian.org/ stretch/updates main 
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian/ stretch-updates main
```

Comment: I already have that in the image, no? Also, it seems to be a new issue with my system. I get a similar unmet dependencies message when tryin to install anything now.

Comment: No ! You have the `deb-src` on your `sources.list`

Comment: Alright, I'll take a look shortly. Why would this cause all these dependency issues while installing any packages though when it worked before?

Comment: Okay, it's worked now, thanks. What's the difference with the deb source at the bottom VS at the top? Do you just prefer to add backports separate? Also, is it normally advised to use `non-free` and `contrib` with security updates?

Comment: the `deb-src` is used to download the source code of a program  , the `deb`  is used to install the program. You can move backports  source to the top , it is not a problem  .  Yes you should use the security update with `non-free` sources

Comment: @GAD3R for debian 9 we should also add the following link that you wrote , to our sources list or another link ??

Comment: @Parsa I have update my answer.

Comment: This is bad for Ubuntu. A simple git installation we have to follow all these steps to simply install a git.

Comment: @WitnessTruth This answer is valid for only for Debian. On Ubuntu you  should have  main , update and security components enabled on your sources.list. You can ask a question to if you have a problem with git installation to get a detailed answer , and you are welcome.

Comment: @GAD3R. Thank you for the answer. I understand your point. However, when I read this answer I was using Ubuntu and I had the exaclty same problem in Ubuntu 18.04 ... :/ Unfortunately...

Comment: @WitnessTruth There is a sample sources.list on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1036415) , exclude the `bionic-backports`, just you need the first 3 lines, Then update and install git. Make sure to have only the 3 lines ( that's why it is hard to answer in a comment without knowing the current sources configuration. Because a duplicate url may cause a problem)

Answer (score 2):

Try `apt-get update && apt-get install git-core`.

I found it in [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-git-on-debian-8).

Comment: The `git-core` package is just a transitional package which unique function is to pull the `git` package.

Comment: @sidahmed I too saw this link earlier. However, I get the error `git-core : Depends: git (> 1:1.7.0.2) but is not going to be installed`.

Comment: I know that this may be obvious, but did you use `apt-get update` ??

Comment: @Sidahmed Indeed.

Comment: okay, clean all the cache with this two commands `sudo apt-get clean` and `sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*`. Then reuse the command in the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-get purge mongodb mongodb-server mongodb-server-core mongodb-clients
sudo apt-get purge mongodb-org
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Use this code. It is working.

[image]

Comment: So the solution is to install some Ubuntu stuff on top of Debian? Good luck with that.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed by only keeping in the sources.list these urls:

```
nano /etc/apt/sources.list

deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main
```

Then I run:

```
# ensure that the shared libraries are properly registered (also fixes some GCC/G++ errors)
sudo ldconfig

#check your package cache
sudo apt-get check

#update your package list
sudo apt-get update

#ensure package downloads were properly completed when the system last updated
sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing

#try to upgrade the system (sometimes an updated package version fixes the issue)
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade

#try to reconfigure all applications that failed to install
sudo dpkg --configure -a

#try to fix broken packages
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Finally:

```
sudo apt-get install git
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran `sudo apt update` followed by `sudo apt upgrade`. After that, `sudo apt install git` worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

There are several materials which I would like to solve problems in Debian Linux 10.

1. Linux (by terminal):
   **uname -a**
   ***uname -mrs***
2. You should download suitable version of the git ([here](https://debian.pkgs.org/10/debian-main-amd64/git_2.20.1-2_amd64.deb.html))
3. Try this command by terminal:
   `sudo dpkg -i git_2.20.1-2_amd64.deb`
4. If you faced the issues dependence problems ([more](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53343241/dependency-problems-leaving-unconfigured)):
   `sudo dpkg --configure -a`
   `sudo apt-get -f install`
   `sudo apt install git_2.20.1-2_amd64.deb --reinstall`
5. You should configure:
   `cd /etc/apt/`
   `nano sources.list`
   (try open all_ )
   `deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian/ stable main contrib non-free`
   `deb http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian jessie main`
6. Just follow this structure:
   `apt-update && apt search ^git`
7. Next also following several command by the terminal:

   --> Make sure that the shared libraries are properly registered (also fixes some GCC/G++ errors)
   **sudo ldconfig**

   --> check your package cache
   **sudo apt-get check**

   --> You should update your package list here
   **sudo apt-get update**

   --> ensure package downloads were properly completed when the system last updated
   **sudo apt-get upgrade --fix-missing**

   --> try to upgrade the system (sometimes an updated package version fixes the issue)
   **sudo apt-get upgrade

   sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**

   --> Strive to reconfigure all applications that failed to install

   `sudo dpkg --configure -a`

   --> try to fix broken packages
   `sudo apt-get install -f`
8. Final Step is just giving processing:
   `sudo apt-get install git`.

Summary:
git is already the newest version (1:2.20.1-2).

You are successfully proceeding all steps.

Comment: Can you explain what the steps do?

Comment: RalfFriedl you can use above explanation content. 
What is exactly issues in your system.

Answer (score 0):

I am new to linux environment so i was facing this issue and unable to find solution for myself. After reading from resources, this helped in my case:

1. Commented everything else in sources.list
2. Added just "deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu 1 bionic main" line.

how to edit sources.list:
[click here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FeNxQiGsaEI)

And the discussion  i found usefull was [Here](https://ubuntu-mate.community/t/cant-install-git/19806/11)