# Unmet dependencies while trying to install Git from

Tags: debian, software-installation, git

I know this kind of questions is often-asked, and I read many of threads (particulary [this one](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/332862/unmet-dependencies-while-installing-git-on-debian)) around that kind of problems without finding a "simple" solution (I mean without editing the `DEBIAN/control` file of the package).

Here's the problem :

```
Lila ~ # apt-get -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 1757 not upgraded.

Lila ~ # cat /etc/apt/sources.list | grep -v '#'
deb [arch=amd64,i386]  http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian/ stretch main non-free contrib
deb http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates main
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports main
deb ftp://ftp.deb-multimedia.org stretch main non-free

Lila ~ # apt-cache policy git
git:
Installed: 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u1
Candidate: 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u1
Version table:
    1:2.14.1-3~bpo9+1 100
        100 http://ftp.debian.org/debian stretch-backports/main amd64 Packages
*** 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u1 500
        500 http://security.debian.org/debian-security stretch/updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
    1:2.11.0-3 500
        500 http://ftp.fr.debian.org/debian stretch/main amd64 Packages

Lila ~ # apt-get install git=1:2.14.1-3~bpo9+1
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
git : Depends: git-man (> 1:2.14.1) but 1:2.11.0-3+deb9u1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

In human-readable format: I have to install git >= 2.13 for work. I'm currently on Debian stable (I've the feeling that this is going to change); and I'm trying to install testing version from backports.

Answer (score 1):

Auto answer:
I finally found I had to tell apt-get to install this version from stretch-backports:

```
apt-get install -t stretch-backports git
```

=> Worked